# Regex number pattern in a fixed length

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I need to validate a field with a fixed length of 8 and it only accept numbers, like `12345678` or `11111118` (these are valid).

But I cannot accept when all numbers are the same, like `11111111`

I came with `^\d{8}(\1*)$` https://regex101.com/r/tH2hB7/1 , but I can´t find the correct pattern to identify the repeating numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `lookahead` for the same.
See demo.

```
^(\d)(?!\1{7}$)\d{7}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/tH2hB7/4